# Internet Explorer - Embedded database

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, embedded-database, mobile-browser, extensible-storage-engine

Every browser do use some embedded database. From Wikipedia information it looks like that Google Chrome use SQLite and LevelDB.

[Wiki for SQLite] - "The browsers Google Chrome, Opera, Safari and the Android Browser all allow for storing information in, and retrieving it from, a SQLite database within the browser...."
[Wiki for LevelDB] - "LevelDB is used as the backend database for Google Chrome's IndexedDB and is one of the supported backends for Riak."

But there is no clear information on what is the browser embedded database for IE. Some people claim in their blogs that it is [Extensible Storage Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine) and some [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact). But unfortunately neither the Wiki pages or some official web page confirms the same.

Is anybody having concrete information on which is the embedded database for IE.

Also, it would be great if there is info for mobile browsers, Firefox and Safari.

**P.S.** I am not looking for information which somebody has put on a blog. I did find those kind of blogs but for me it is difficult to trust. I am more looking for information provided by some official community, web page etc.

Comment: Its simple. Close Internet Explorer, open a command prompt and cd to C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Indexed DB\, then run "esentutl.exe Internet.edb". It's an ESE database.

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest - Thanks, I got that.

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest - A kind suggestion - you should probably give answers using "Your Answer" option instead of "add a comment". It would help the user to mark your answer as helpful and also this will increase your StackOverflow reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to confirm this yourself. If you close Internet Explorer, open a command prompt and cd to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Indexed DB\, then run "esentutl.exe Internet.edb". You can see it is an ESE database.